# Get file.separator of a specified file path

Tags: java, file, operating-system, separator

How do you get a file separator of a specified file/folder path?

In Java, we can write, for example

```
File f = new File("C:\\MyFolder\\MyText.txt");
```

Keep in mind this is a file representation (the file does not have to exist physically). So given any specified path, is there a method that can return the separator for that specified path only?

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

The `File.pathSeparator` and `File.pathSeparatorChar` returns system dependent file separator, but what I want is the separator for a given path, like in the above case `\`, even if the above program is run and the path is not valid for *nix

Comment: All paths have the separator `File.separator`.

Comment: In other words, on Linux, `f` is a perfectly valid path, with the separator `/`, referring to a file called `C:\MyFolder\MyTest.txt` in the current directory. (Backslashes are allowed in filenames on Linux)

Comment: I want the separator for that specified path, not OS dependent

Comment: Then your program needs to keep track of it somehow, `File` won't do it for you.

Comment: Check which one is present in the string? (Also sometimes "c:\folder/file.txt" can be accepted... so really you'd better just normalize path by replacing either slash with current one).

Comment: Imagine if there *was* a way to do this... then how would you create a File object referring to `C:\MyFolder\MyText.txt` in the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separator character for `File` objects is always given by `File.separator` (or `File.separatorChar`). There is no way to construct a `File` object with an unusual separator; they always hold paths that are valid on the current system.

```
File f = new File("C:\\MyFolder\\MyText.txt");
```

After executing this line on Windows, `f` refers to a `File` object that refers to the file `MyText.txt` in the folder `MyFolder` on drive `C:`, as you probably intended.

But on Linux, `f` refers to a `File` object that refers to the file `C:\MyFolder\MyText.txt` in the current directory. (On Linux, backslashes are allowed in filenames)

Imagine if there was a way to do this. If you had a File constructed with `new File("a/b\\c")`, then how would you know whether it was referring to the file `b\c` in the folder `a` (with separator `/`), or the file `c` in the folder `a/b` (with separator `\`)?

It can't, so it should be clear that there is no reliable way to do this. If your program handles paths with unusual separators, then your program needs to handle them itself. `File` cannot do it for you.

Comment: So what happens when you call mkdirs for the above example? Is the behavior platform dependent?

Comment: @Nederealm What specifically are you asking about? It creates the specified directory, and its parent directory recursively if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: does it create folders b\c in folder a or folders a/b, since its not able to know if c is a file?

Comment: @Nederealm That's not really to do with mkdirs, but to do with File. On Linux, `new File("a/b\\c")` is the file or folder called `b\c` inside the folder `a`, so mkdirs will create that. On Windows (where \\ is the main separator but / is also allowed) it's the file or folder called `c` inside the folder called `b` inside the folder called `a`, so mkdirs would create that. On some hypothetical operating system where \\ is the only separator, it's the file or folder called `c` inside the folder `a\b`, so mkdirs would create that.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with `System.getProperty("user.home")`. And, you could use [`File.seperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) like

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + 
        File.seperator + "MyText.txt");
```

but I would prefer [`File(String parent, String child)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "MyText.txt");
System.out.println(f.getPath());
```